# Play audio from file to speaker with Media Foundation

Tags: windows, audio, ms-media-foundation

I'm attempting to play the audio track from an mp4 file to my speaker. I know Media Foundation is able to decode the audio stream as I can play it with the TopoEdit tool.

In the sample code below I'm not using a media session or topology. I'm attempting to manually connect the media source to the sink writer. The reason I want to do this is that I ultimately intend to be getting the source samples from the network rather than from a file.

The error I get on the pSinkWriter->WriteSample line when running the sample below is MF_E_INVALIDREQUEST (0xC00D36B2). So I suspect there's something I haven't wired up correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <mfapi.h>
#include <mfplay.h>
#include <mfreadwrite.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "mf.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "mfplat.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "mfplay.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "mfreadwrite.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "mfuuid.lib")

#define CHECK_HR(hr, msg) if (hr != S_OK) { printf(msg); printf("Error: %.2X.\n", hr); goto done; }

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE);
    MFStartup(MF_VERSION);

    IMFSourceResolver *pSourceResolver = NULL;
    IUnknown* uSource = NULL;
    IMFMediaSource *mediaFileSource = NULL;
    IMFSourceReader *pSourceReader = NULL;
    IMFMediaType *pAudioOutType = NULL;
    IMFMediaType *pFileAudioMediaType = NULL;
    MF_OBJECT_TYPE ObjectType = MF_OBJECT_INVALID;
    IMFMediaSink *pAudioSink = NULL;
    IMFStreamSink *pStreamSink = NULL;
    IMFMediaTypeHandler *pMediaTypeHandler = NULL;
    IMFMediaType *pMediaType = NULL;
    IMFMediaType *pSinkMediaType = NULL;
    IMFSinkWriter *pSinkWriter = NULL;

    // Set up the reader for the file.
    CHECK_HR(MFCreateSourceResolver(&pSourceResolver), "MFCreateSourceResolver failed.\n");

    CHECK_HR(pSourceResolver->CreateObjectFromURL(
        L"big_buck_bunny.mp4",      // URL of the source.
        MF_RESOLUTION_MEDIASOURCE,  // Create a source object.
        NULL,                       // Optional property store.
        &ObjectType,                // Receives the created object type. 
        &uSource                    // Receives a pointer to the media source.
        ), "Failed to create media source resolver for file.\n");

    CHECK_HR(uSource->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&mediaFileSource)),
        "Failed to create media file source.\n");

    CHECK_HR(MFCreateSourceReaderFromMediaSource(mediaFileSource, NULL, &pSourceReader), 
        "Error creating media source reader.\n");

    CHECK_HR(pSourceReader->GetCurrentMediaType((DWORD)MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_AUDIO_STREAM, &pFileAudioMediaType), 
        "Error retrieving current media type from first audio stream.\n");

    // printf("File Media Type:\n");
    // Dump pFileAudioMediaType.

    // Set the audio output type on the source reader.
    CHECK_HR(MFCreateMediaType(&pAudioOutType), "Failed to create audio output media type.\n");
    CHECK_HR(pAudioOutType->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Audio), "Failed to set audio output media major type.\n");
    CHECK_HR(pAudioOutType->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFAudioFormat_Float), "Failed to set audio output audio sub type (Float).\n");

    CHECK_HR(pSourceReader->SetCurrentMediaType((DWORD)MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_AUDIO_STREAM, NULL, pAudioOutType), 
        "Error setting reader audio output type.\n");

    // printf("Source Reader Output Type:");
    // Dump pAudioOutType.

    CHECK_HR(MFCreateAudioRenderer(NULL, &pAudioSink), "Failed to create audio sink.\n");

    CHECK_HR(pAudioSink->GetStreamSinkByIndex(0, &pStreamSink), "Failed to get audio renderer stream by index.\n");

    CHECK_HR(pStreamSink->GetMediaTypeHandler(&pMediaTypeHandler), "Failed to get media type handler.\n");

    // My speaker has 3 audio types of which I got the furthesr with the third one.
    CHECK_HR(pMediaTypeHandler->GetMediaTypeByIndex(2, &pSinkMediaType), "Failed to get sink media type.\n");

    CHECK_HR(pMediaTypeHandler->SetCurrentMediaType(pSinkMediaType), "Failed to set current media type.\n");

    // printf("Sink Media Type:\n");
    // Dump pSinkMediaType.

    CHECK_HR(MFCreateSinkWriterFromMediaSink(pAudioSink, NULL, &pSinkWriter), "Failed to create sink writer from audio sink.\n");

    printf("Read audio samples from file and write to speaker.\n");

    IMFSample *audioSample = NULL;
    DWORD streamIndex, flags;
    LONGLONG llAudioTimeStamp;

    for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++)
    //while (true)
    {
        // Initial read results in a null pSample??
        CHECK_HR(pSourceReader->ReadSample(
            MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_AUDIO_STREAM,
            0,                              // Flags.
            &streamIndex,                   // Receives the actual stream index. 
            &flags,                         // Receives status flags.
            &llAudioTimeStamp,              // Receives the time stamp.
            &audioSample                    // Receives the sample or NULL.
            ), "Error reading audio sample.");

        if (flags & MF_SOURCE_READERF_ENDOFSTREAM)
        {
            printf("End of stream.\n");
            break;
        }
        if (flags & MF_SOURCE_READERF_STREAMTICK)
        {
            printf("Stream tick.\n");
            pSinkWriter->SendStreamTick(0, llAudioTimeStamp);
        }

        if (!audioSample)
        {
            printf("Null audio sample.\n");
        }
        else
        {
            CHECK_HR(audioSample->SetSampleTime(llAudioTimeStamp), "Error setting the audio sample time.\n");

            CHECK_HR(pSinkWriter->WriteSample(0, audioSample), "The stream sink writer was not happy with the sample.\n");
        }
    }

done:

    printf("finished.\n");
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

I've omitted the code that dumps the media types for brevity but their output is shown below. It could well be that I haven't got the media types connected properly.

```
File Media Type:
Audio: MAJOR_TYPE=Audio, PREFER_WAVEFORMATEX=1, {BFBABE79-7434-4D1C-94F0-72A3B9E17188}=0, {7632F0E6-9538-4D61-ACDA-EA29C8C14456}=0, SUBTYPE={00001610-0000-0010-8000-00AA00389B71}, NUM_CHANNELS=2, SAMPLES_PER_SECOND=22050, BLOCK_ALIGNMENT=1, AVG_BYTES_PER_SECOND=8000, BITS_PER_SAMPLE=16, USER_DATA=<BLOB>, {73D1072D-1870-4174-A063-29FF4FF6C11E}={05589F81-C356-11CE-BF01-00AA0055595A}, ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT=1, FIXED_SIZE_SAMPLES=1, SAMPLE_SIZE=1, MPEG4_SAMPLE_DESCRIPTION=<BLOB>, MPEG4_CURRENT_SAMPLE_ENTRY=0, AVG_BITRATE=64000, 

Source Reader Output Type:
Audio: MAJOR_TYPE=Audio, SUBTYPE=Float, 

Sink Media Type:
Audio: MAJOR_TYPE=Audio, SUBTYPE=Float, NUM_CHANNELS=2, SAMPLES_PER_SECOND=48000, BLOCK_ALIGNMENT=8, AVG_BYTES_PER_SECOND=384000, BITS_PER_SAMPLE=32, ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT=1, CHANNEL_MASK=3,
```

Any hints as to where I could look next would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing the sink writer BeginWriting call.

```
CHECK_HR(pSinkWriter->BeginWriting(), "Sink writer begin writing call failed.\n");
```

That got some audio coming out of the speakers but it has a very bad chop to it so there's something else I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

The Media Type you are setting to the Reader is incomplete.
MF_MT_AUDIO_AVG_BYTES_PER_SECOND
MF_MT_AUDIO_BLOCK_ALIGNMENT
and MF_MT_AUDIO_NUM_CHANNELS
are missing.

i would set the media type you retrieved from the sink mediatypehandler.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Tried those things but to no avail. The output type from the mediatypehandler is not suitable to be set on the reader. Full sample is available here if it has piqued your interest https://github.com/sipsorcery/mediafoundationsamples/tree/master/MFAudio.