# How to play audio using Sink Writer from Microsoft Media Foundation

Tags: c++, audio, com, playback, ms-media-foundation

I'm trying to create an audio visualizer using Microsoft Media Foundation. For this I need to intercept the samples and simultaneously play them. Using a Media Session with Topology and a sample-grabber sink seems impractical and over-complicated, hence I'm trying to use a combination of a Sink Reader and Sink Writer for this (see the right half of the image on [Overview of the Media Foundation Architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/medfound/overview-of-the-media-foundation-architecture)). Unfortunately, [Audio/Video Playback](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/medfound/audio-video-playback) does not really explain how to do this. The book *Developing Microsoft Media Foundation Applications* contains a source-to-sink loop on page 92, but that still does not really help me.

Creating the Source Reader works fine and I'm reading nonzero samples. Writing them to the Sink Writer (which uses the Streaming Audio Renderer) does not give me any errors, but I don't hear anything. I tried multiple things like selecting other media types and explicitly selecting the rendering device (although I only have one, as it indicated), but to no avail. Note that playing audio using a Media Session works fine, though!

I based my code on this question: [Play audio from file to speaker with Media Foundation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28235464/4454665).

This is my code at this moment:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <cassert>

#include <mfidl.h>
#include <mfapi.h>
#include <mfreadwrite.h>
#include <Mferror.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "mf")
#pragma comment(lib, "mfplat")
#pragma comment(lib, "mfreadwrite")

#include <winrt/base.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "windowsapp")

void winHr(const HRESULT result) { winrt::check_hresult(result); }

template<class T>
struct ComPtr : winrt::com_ptr<T>
{
    auto operator&() noexcept { return this->put(); }

    operator T*() noexcept
    {
        assert(this->get());
        return this->get();
    }
};

int main() noexcept
{
    winHr(CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE));
    winHr(MFStartup(MF_VERSION));

    {
        ComPtr<IMFSourceReader> reader;
        winHr(MFCreateSourceReaderFromURL(
            LR"(test.wav)",
            nullptr, &reader));

        constexpr auto inStreamIndex = MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_AUDIO_STREAM;

        // Select only the audio stream
        winHr(reader->SetStreamSelection(MF_SOURCE_READER_ALL_STREAMS, false));
        winHr(reader->SetStreamSelection(inStreamIndex, true));

        ComPtr<IMFMediaSink> mediaSink;
        winHr(MFCreateAudioRenderer(nullptr, &mediaSink));

        ComPtr<IMFSinkWriter> writer;

        {
            ComPtr<IMFStreamSink> streamSink;
            winHr(mediaSink->GetStreamSinkByIndex(0, &streamSink));

            ComPtr<IMFMediaTypeHandler> typeHandler;
            winHr(streamSink->GetMediaTypeHandler(&typeHandler));

            ComPtr<IMFMediaType> inputType;
            winHr(reader->GetCurrentMediaType(inStreamIndex, &inputType));

            ComPtr<IMFMediaType> closestSupportedType;
            const auto result = typeHandler->IsMediaTypeSupported(inputType, &closestSupportedType);
            if (result == MF_E_INVALIDMEDIATYPE)
            {
                if (!closestSupportedType)
                {
                    std::cerr << "Media type not supported" << std::endl;
                    winHr(mediaSink->Shutdown());
                    goto end; //:o
                }
                winHr(reader->SetCurrentMediaType(inStreamIndex, nullptr, closestSupportedType));
                winHr(typeHandler->SetCurrentMediaType(closestSupportedType));
                winHr(MFCreateSinkWriterFromMediaSink(mediaSink, nullptr, &writer));
                winHr(writer->SetInputMediaType(0, closestSupportedType, nullptr));
            }
            else {
                winHr(result);
                winHr(reader->SetCurrentMediaType(inStreamIndex, nullptr, inputType));
                winHr(typeHandler->SetCurrentMediaType(inputType));
                winHr(MFCreateSinkWriterFromMediaSink(mediaSink, nullptr, &writer));
                winHr(writer->SetInputMediaType(0, inputType, nullptr));
            }
        }

        winHr(writer->BeginWriting());
        while (true)
        {
            ComPtr<IMFSample> sample;
            DWORD streamFlags;
            MFTIME timestamp;
            winHr(reader->ReadSample(inStreamIndex, 0, nullptr, &streamFlags, &timestamp, &sample));

            if (streamFlags & MF_SOURCE_READERF_ENDOFSTREAM)
            {
                winHr(writer->NotifyEndOfSegment(0));
                break;
            }
            if (streamFlags & MF_SOURCE_READERF_STREAMTICK)
                winHr(writer->SendStreamTick(0, timestamp));

            if (!sample) continue;

            winHr(sample->SetSampleTime(timestamp));
            winHr(writer->WriteSample(0, sample));
        }
        winHr(writer->Flush(0));

        std::cout << "(Press enter to stop)" << std::endl;
        std::cin.get();

        winHr(writer->Finalize());
        writer.attach(nullptr);
        winHr(mediaSink->Shutdown());
    }

end:
    winHr(MFShutdown());
    CoUninitialize();
}
```

<s>Just to be clear: when I run this it prints `(Press enter to stop)` and I can hear from the noise (read: distortions from electronic signals) from my headphones that I can deduce that for a short moment an audio port was opened and then closed, but no actual audio is played. How can I get this to work?</s>

<s>Edit 1: I just fixed that if `result != MF_E_INVALIDMEDIATYPE` I didn't set the media type, but now I often (but not always, for some reason) get `MF_E_TOPO_CODEC_NOT_FOUND` at the line `winHr(writer->SetInputMediaType(0, inputType, nullptr));`. Why would this be? (Still no audio is played in any case.)</s>

Edit 2: Apparently it matters when I create the writer, so now I do that only at the last moment, but now I get the "Media type not supported" error. Maybe I need to manually pick some media type but I will look in to this later -- unless someone knows the answer.

Comment: You can check this code to see if it works:  https://github.com/sipsorcery/mediafoundationsamples/blob/master/MFAudio/MFAudio.cpp.  Check line after the following comment "My speaker has 3 audio types but I was only able to get anywhere with the third one."

Comment: @VuVirt Thanks for responding! I already tried similar code (from the linked question), which didn't work no matter which media type index I chose; but apparently this code is different since with type 3 it does output something - but it plays much too fast, probably because the types don't fully match. Of course this is already better than nothing, but unfortunately it is far from a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your code to work differently in the following manner:
1. Enumerates the Audio Sink output media types, until it finds a supported one.
2. Sets this media type to the Reader in order to force it to use Audio Resampler DSP (this is what IMFMediaTopology does).

Here is the code, it plays back the input wav file properly. Let me know if it works for you.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <cassert>

#include <mfidl.h>
#include <mfapi.h>
#include <mfreadwrite.h>
#include <Mferror.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "mf")
#pragma comment(lib, "mfplat")
#pragma comment(lib, "mfreadwrite")

#include <winrt/base.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "windowsapp")

void winHr(const HRESULT result) { winrt::check_hresult(result); }

template<class T>
struct ComPtr : winrt::com_ptr<T>
{
    auto operator&() noexcept { return this->put(); }

    operator T*() noexcept
    {
        assert(this->get());
        return this->get();
    }
};

int main() noexcept
{
    winHr(CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE));
    winHr(MFStartup(MF_VERSION));

    {
        ComPtr<IMFSourceReader> reader;
        winHr(MFCreateSourceReaderFromURL(
            LR"(test.wav)",
            nullptr, &reader));

        constexpr auto inStreamIndex = MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_AUDIO_STREAM;

        // Select only the audio stream
        winHr(reader->SetStreamSelection(MF_SOURCE_READER_ALL_STREAMS, false));
        winHr(reader->SetStreamSelection(inStreamIndex, true));

        ComPtr<IMFMediaSink> mediaSink;
        winHr(MFCreateAudioRenderer(nullptr, &mediaSink));

        ComPtr<IMFSinkWriter> writer;

        {
            ComPtr<IMFStreamSink> streamSink;
            winHr(mediaSink->GetStreamSinkByIndex(0, &streamSink));

            ComPtr<IMFMediaTypeHandler> typeHandler;
            winHr(streamSink->GetMediaTypeHandler(&typeHandler));

            DWORD dwCount = 0;
            ComPtr<IMFMediaType> inputType;
            winHr(typeHandler->GetMediaTypeCount(&dwCount));

            for (INT i = 0; i < dwCount; i++)
            {
                inputType.attach(nullptr);
                winHr(typeHandler->GetMediaTypeByIndex(i, &inputType));
                if (SUCCEEDED(typeHandler->IsMediaTypeSupported(inputType, NULL)))
                    break;
            }

            //ComPtr<IMFMediaType> inputType;
            //winHr(reader->GetCurrentMediaType(inStreamIndex, &inputType));

            winHr(reader->SetCurrentMediaType(inStreamIndex, NULL, inputType));


            //ComPtr<IMFMediaType> closestSupportedType;
            //const auto result = typeHandler->IsMediaTypeSupported(inputType, &closestSupportedType);
            //if (result == MF_E_INVALIDMEDIATYPE)
            //{
            //  if (!closestSupportedType)
            //  {
            //      std::cerr << "Media type not supported" << std::endl;
            //      winHr(mediaSink->Shutdown());
            //      goto end; //:o
            //  }
            //  winHr(reader->SetCurrentMediaType(inStreamIndex, nullptr, closestSupportedType));
            //  winHr(typeHandler->SetCurrentMediaType(closestSupportedType));
            //  winHr(MFCreateSinkWriterFromMediaSink(mediaSink, nullptr, &writer));
            //  winHr(writer->SetInputMediaType(0, closestSupportedType, nullptr));
            //}
            //else 
            {
                //winHr(result);
                //winHr(reader->SetCurrentMediaType(inStreamIndex, nullptr, inputType));
                winHr(typeHandler->SetCurrentMediaType(inputType));
                winHr(MFCreateSinkWriterFromMediaSink(mediaSink, nullptr, &writer));
                winHr(writer->SetInputMediaType(0, inputType, nullptr));
            }
        }

        winHr(writer->BeginWriting());
        while (true)
        {
            ComPtr<IMFSample> sample;
            DWORD streamFlags;
            MFTIME timestamp;
            winHr(reader->ReadSample(inStreamIndex, 0, nullptr, &streamFlags, &timestamp, &sample));

            if (streamFlags & MF_SOURCE_READERF_ENDOFSTREAM)
            {
                winHr(writer->NotifyEndOfSegment(0));
                break;
            }
            if (streamFlags & MF_SOURCE_READERF_STREAMTICK)
                winHr(writer->SendStreamTick(0, timestamp));

            if (!sample) 
                continue;

            // SetSampleTime is redundant
            //winHr(sample->SetSampleTime(timestamp));
            winHr(writer->WriteSample(0, sample));
        }

        // Flush shouldn't be called! 
        // winHr(writer->Flush(0));

        std::cout << "(Press enter to stop)" << std::endl;
        std::cin.get();

        winHr(writer->Finalize());
        writer.attach(nullptr);
        winHr(mediaSink->Shutdown());
    }

end:
    winHr(MFShutdown());
    CoUninitialize();
}
```

Comment: Woah this works, thanks so much! I do still have a couple of questions, though: (1) [Documentation for `GetMediaTypeCount/-ByIndex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/api/mfidl/nn-mfidl-imfmediatypehandler) tells me that these only deal with supported media types, so why does `IsMediaTypeSupported` still fail for some of them? (2) `inputType.detach()` doesn't release the interface right? (3) Where did you find this is what `IMFMediaTopology` does? Now I hope that the supported type is usable for my visualizer; maybe I need to convert it someway...

Comment: (1) I think it depends on which audio output is currently connected. (2) inputType should be released prior to next call to GetMediaTypeByIndex (3) https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/medfound/about-topologies - "The Media Session completes the topology by using an object called the topology loader. The topology loader converts partial topologies into full topologies by inserting the needed transforms. The process of conversion is called resolving the topology." Media type is float -1.0 to 1.0 easy to visualize. Consider accepting the answer and posting other questions separately.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Sorry but I won't accept an answer until my question is really answered (I won't forget it though, I've been here for quite a while), so here you go.

Comment: Oh; forgot to follow up on this: `inputType.detach();` is not the right method to use here, as it does not actually Release the interface! You should use eg. `inputType.attach(nullptr);` (or if one uses `ATL::CComPtr`: `.Release` (not `->Release`)). Could you fix this for future reference?

Comment: It doesn't work for me (no error, just does nothing like all code exposed here and there so far). Win 10 x64 6.3.17763. Sink writers are meant for encoding, not rendering, that's the problem...

Comment: @SimonMourier maybe you should to manually enumerate the renderer’s media types and try each one of them. Does it work with IMFTopology? Have you also tested TopoEdit?

Comment: TopoEdit works fine. The resolver adds a Resampler transform. I think resampling may be needed in the general case. Something like this : https://github.com/sipsorcery/mediafoundationsamples/blob/master/MFAudioMFT/MFAudioMFT.cpp (but it doesn't work for me either as is).

Comment: @SimonMourier OP here; I found the culprit: remove the `winHr(writer->Flush(0));` at the end! (Could you update the answer again @VuVirt? ;)

Comment: Oh, and btw: the `winHr(sample->SetSampleTime(timestamp));` seems to be unnecessary

Comment: Yes you are right. The Flush must be removed, it cuts sound. Also it seems SetSampleTime is not necessary.

Comment: @SimonMourier. Le Sink Writer est aussi capable de faire du rendu audio. Je viens d'ailleurs de le découvrir avec cette question. Je vais mettre à jour mon code pour prendre en charge le fichier test.wav. J'avoue avoir galéré, et ce n'est pas non plus la méthode optimale, mais ça marche sur mon ordi. Pour être optimale, il faudrait récupérer les capacités de la carte son actuelle. Je peux développer et ajouter du code si nécessaire.

Comment: @SimonMourier. I changed my code to manage your test.wav file. I also included the remarks of SWdV.

Comment: Calls to SetSampleTime and Flush are now commented out. Thanks! Je vous remercie a tous!

Answer (score 0):

This code works just fine for me with wav files (Win7, default sound card) :

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Main.cpp
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma once
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define STRICT

#pragma comment(lib, "mfplat")
#pragma comment(lib, "mfreadwrite")
#pragma comment(lib, "mf")
#pragma comment(lib, "mfuuid")

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7
#include <WinSDKVer.h>
#include <new>
#include <windows.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <mfapi.h>
#include <mfidl.h>
#include <mferror.h>
#include <mfreadwrite.h>

template <class T> inline void SAFE_RELEASE(T*& p){

    if(p){
        p->Release();
        p = NULL;
    }
}

#define AUDIO_FILE L"C:\\Project\\Media\\Audio\\test.wav"

HRESULT ProcessAudio(const WCHAR*);

void main(){

    HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE);

    if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){

        hr = MFStartup(MF_VERSION, MFSTARTUP_LITE);

        if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){

            hr = ProcessAudio(AUDIO_FILE);

            hr = MFShutdown();
        }

        CoUninitialize();
    }
}

HRESULT ProcessAudio(const WCHAR*){

    IMFSourceReader* pSourceReader = NULL;
    IMFMediaType* pType = NULL;
    DWORD dwMediaTypeIndex = 0;
    IMFMediaSink* pAudioSink = NULL;
    IMFStreamSink* pStreamSink = NULL;
    IMFMediaTypeHandler* pMediaTypeHandler = NULL;
    IMFSinkWriter* pSinkWriter = NULL;

    HRESULT hr = MFCreateSourceReaderFromURL(AUDIO_FILE, NULL, &pSourceReader);

    // Check native media type
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
        hr = pSourceReader->GetNativeMediaType((DWORD)MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_AUDIO_STREAM, dwMediaTypeIndex, &pType);

    SAFE_RELEASE(pType);

    // Get current media type
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
        hr = pSourceReader->GetCurrentMediaType(dwMediaTypeIndex, &pType);

    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
        hr = MFCreateAudioRenderer(NULL, &pAudioSink);

    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
        hr = pAudioSink->GetStreamSinkByIndex(0, &pStreamSink);

    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
        hr = pStreamSink->GetMediaTypeHandler(&pMediaTypeHandler);

    if(FAILED(hr = pMediaTypeHandler->IsMediaTypeSupported(pType, NULL))){

        SAFE_RELEASE(pType);

        // This is a compatible type with my soundcard
        // MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE                     MFMediaType_Audio
        // MF_MT_SUBTYPE                        MFAudioFormat_PCM
        // MF_MT_AUDIO_NUM_CHANNELS             2
        // MF_MT_AUDIO_SAMPLES_PER_SECOND       48000
        // MF_MT_AUDIO_BLOCK_ALIGNMENT          4
        // MF_MT_AUDIO_AVG_BYTES_PER_SECOND     192000
        // MF_MT_AUDIO_BITS_PER_SAMPLE          16
        // MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT        1
        // MF_MT_AUDIO_PREFER_WAVEFORMATEX      1

        hr = MFCreateMediaType(&pType);

        if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
            hr = pType->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Audio);

        if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
            hr = pType->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFAudioFormat_PCM);

        if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
            hr = pType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_NUM_CHANNELS, 2);

        if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
            hr = pType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_SAMPLES_PER_SECOND, 48000);

        if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
            hr = pType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_BLOCK_ALIGNMENT, 4);

        if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
            hr = pType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_AVG_BYTES_PER_SECOND, 192000);

        if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
            hr = pType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_BITS_PER_SAMPLE, 16);

        if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
            hr = pType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT, TRUE);

        if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
            hr = pType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_PREFER_WAVEFORMATEX, TRUE);
    }

    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
        hr = pMediaTypeHandler->SetCurrentMediaType(pType);

    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
        hr = MFCreateSinkWriterFromMediaSink(pAudioSink, NULL, &pSinkWriter);

    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
        hr = pSinkWriter->BeginWriting();

    BOOL bProcess = (hr == S_OK ? TRUE : FALSE);
    DWORD streamIndex;
    DWORD flags;
    LONGLONG llTimeStamp;
    IMFSample* pSample = NULL;

    while(bProcess){

        hr = pSourceReader->ReadSample((DWORD)MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_AUDIO_STREAM, 0, &streamIndex, &flags, &llTimeStamp, &pSample);

        if(SUCCEEDED(hr) && (flags == 0)){

            if(pSample){

                hr = pSinkWriter->WriteSample(0, pSample);

                SAFE_RELEASE(pSample);
            }
        }
        else{

            bProcess = FALSE;
        }
    }

    if(pSinkWriter)
        pSinkWriter->Finalize();

    if(pAudioSink)
        pAudioSink->Shutdown();

    SAFE_RELEASE(pSample);
    SAFE_RELEASE(pSinkWriter);
    SAFE_RELEASE(pMediaTypeHandler);
    SAFE_RELEASE(pStreamSink);
    SAFE_RELEASE(pAudioSink);
    SAFE_RELEASE(pType);
    SAFE_RELEASE(pSourceReader);

    return hr;
}
```

If you face problem with MF_E_TOPO_CODEC_NOT_FOUND, share your file. Perhaps extra code is needed in this case.

**EDIT**

- Do you have more than one sound card ?
- Share your audio file, so we can see what's going on.

My little hack with Sleep(40), is just here to tell you that doing "while(true)" without pausing have no sens (your processor is working too much). Off course 40 should be better decided. 40 is the minimum processing time processor preemption on windows OS. That my choice for this sample code. We can talk about the best way to choose this value. I'm waiting for your suggestion.

Comment: That's weird because this code doesn't do anything for me... (It runs but gives no actual audio output. Maybe you are playing some file of which the codec is incidentally directly supported by your speakers.) Anyway, the `Sleep` is pretty hacky.
I edited my question with some new discovery btw; COM is weird.

Comment: I don't have more than one sound card AFAIK. I tested with multiple audio files, MP3 and WAV (PCM 16-bit LE mono). Also see the other answer and question edits. About the sleep: I didn't use `MF_SINK_WRITER_DISABLE_THROTTLING` so this should be fine I think.

Comment: Yes, i didn't pay attention to the writesample behaviour. It should be fine. Good point.